# Edit joomla template according to my design template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I just want to know can I customized joomla template to looks like my design template ? I already designed  a template for customer. But  he needs to develop his website using joomla. So I have to put my template to the joomla. is that possible ? if it is please send me some reference. I'm going thought with references.

Comment: Take a look at the default template for Joomla 2.5 to see how it works. You will probably be best off editing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla templates are based around a PHP index file and allow you to create overrides for each of the content types output by Joomla.

The [Joomla Doc's site](http://docs.joomla.org) has a [section on templates](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aDevelopers#Templates) that you should start with.

Make sure you read up on [Template Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla_2.5) and [Module Chrome](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome) as well. Reviewing the templates installed by Joomla is also a good place to start. You can get a good feel for how they are structured and what they're capable of by looking at the default templates.

By the way if your client is only just building their website now they should be starting with Joomla 3.2 not 2.5, it has [a lot of great features](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aWhat%27s_new_in_Joomla!) and is very Bootstrap friendly. In fact the tag line for [the 3 series is "Mobile Ready"](http://www.joomla.org/3/en)

Template systems like [JooStrap](http://www.joostrap.com/) also have [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) integrated already.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know can I customized joomla template to looks like my
> design template ?

That's tedious works; the opposite is easier. Your design can be turned to Joomla template. Just add template codes to your HTML and your design can be used as Joomla template.

For example, you need to add the following code before `<html>`:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?>
```

For a basic guide, visit: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

There are also codes to display your website contents and modules.

Comment: If you are able to provide Joomla support, please register at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and help us to resolve some questions.  More hands makes for light work.